# div search-container not getting centered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to center the search container
in a jumbotron, I tried centering using the previous posts about centering a div element yet, it doesn't result so.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/zXprXPv.jpg?3');
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #040404;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  top: 383px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="search-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add an additional class to your `.container` element such as `center-me` and then give that class a property of `text-align:center` for horizontal alignment

Comment: Do u need vertical or horizontal centering or both?

Comment: ya both vertical and horizontal @Trix

Comment: @d_CoDE44 please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896566/div-search-container-not-getting-centered/34900669#34900669)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of solutions to the **Vertical and Horizontal centering** a child in parent.

Considering browser compatibility, one attitude is this:

Assign `text-align: center` to the parent `div` and use `display: inline-block` along with `vertical-align: middle` for the child:

```
.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron .container{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to write a css class named `centered`. I have written and did the changes might fix your problem too.

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/zXprXPv.jpg?3');
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #040404;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  top: 383px;
}

.centered {
  margin: auto;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
<div class="search-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 centered">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this css for centering the element both verticacal and horizontal. 
Below css will make .search-container center relative to jambotron.

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
}
.search-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Note: Search container will have its own width and height, transform will translate the element -50% horizontally and vertically, to make it center to the relative parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just add text-align:center to your .container class for horizontal alignment

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/zXprXPv.jpg?3');
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #040404;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  top: 383px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="search-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/zXprXPv.jpg?3');
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   position: relative;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #040404;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
```

Check JsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/ozLp93tg/

Answer (score -1):

you need to set your `.col-lg-8` to `text-align: center;`.
You can take a look here: `https://jsfiddle.net/kf93ufw7/`

and if you want center it vertical use this:

```
.search-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

link here: `https://jsfiddle.net/kf93ufw7/1/`

Comment: but it should be placed both horizontally and vertically centered

Comment: You should not apply this CSS property to a bootstrap column class as this could have side effects in later development when using `.col-lg-8` where you don't want it's contents centred. A new class should be added ;)